# Connect to a socket server in golang

Tags: go, socket.io-client

I am using this library in golang to connect to socket server.https://github.com/hesh915/go-socket.io-client I have to pass an auth object as server is expecting an object which will authenticate the user, but in this implementation, query seems to take map as a parameter. I get an EOF error while sending the stringified struct to Query as given below:

```
opts.Query["auth"] = str
```

I have created a nested structure for that purpose, tried converting struct into byte data using marshal and type casted into string, passed it as key value pair to map but that didn't seem to work out. Here is how my auth nested struct looks like:

```
{"userInfo":{"id":"","username":"","permissionsInfo":{"permissions"["",""]}},"additionalInfo":""}
```

How to send this information with the implementation given below:

```
opts := &socketio_client.Options{
    Transport: "websocket",
    Query:     make(map[string]string),
}
opts.Query["user"] = "user"
opts.Query["pwd"] = "pass"
uri := "http://192.168.1.70:9090/socket.io/"
```

I have provided the link to the library.

**Minimal Reproducible Example**

```
type User struct {
Userinfo       UserInfo `json:"userInfo"`
AdditionalInfo string   `json:"additionalInfo"`
}
type UserInfo struct {
Id              string          `json:"id"`
Username        string          `json:"username"`
Permissionsinfo PermissionsInfo `json:"permissionInfo"`
}
type PermissionsInfo struct {
Permissions []string `json:"permissions"`
}

func main() {
user := &User{
    Userinfo: UserInfo{
        Id:       "",
        Username: "",
        Permissionsinfo: PermissionsInfo{
            Permissions: []string{"", ""},
        }},
    AdditionalInfo: "",
}

b, _ := json.Marshal(user)
fmt.Println(string(b))

opts := &socketio_client.Options{
    Transport: "websocket",
    Query:     make(map[string]string),
}

opts.Query["auth"] = string(b)

uri := origin + "/socket.io"
client, err := socketio_client.NewClient(uri, opts)

if err != nil {
    if err == io.EOF {
        fmt.Printf("NewClient error:%v\n", err)
        return
    }
 return
}
client.On("error", func() {
    fmt.Println("on error")
})

}
```

The error to the above code, that i'm getting:

```
NewClient error EOF
```

My server end has to receive the auth params as `socket.handshake.auth` and that's understandable because the above functionality doesn't supports for `auth` instead it does for `query`. How can I achieve this functionality? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: hello, it would help if you could provide a minimal, reproducible example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and the exact error you are getting.

Comment: Updated the question with minimal reproducible example.

Comment: You forgot to add the exact error that you are getting.

I also noticed that in the sample code, if the error is not nil and is not io.EOF, you keep going, while you should return the error also in that case...

Comment: Added a return statement, & the error to the above code.

Comment: Can you please review the code? @marco.m